# Problems When I'm trying to deploy a shared Domain in Mule Standalone but not in Anypoint

Tags: mule

I’m trying to test the concept of shared resources, sharing an HTTP connector.

The applications are very simple, in each app only an HTTP inbound connector and a set Payload to give a response.

In Anypoint these apps work perfectly with the domain but when I want to deploy it in mule standalone, I have an error because the apps aren’t able to find the domain.

I have checked a lot of things:

- The domain is deployed in domain folder and the apps in the app
  folder
- I'm using the same Mule version in Anypoint and standalone
- The zip has been created using Anypoint.
- The domain seems to be correctly deployed ( I've got the anchor file
  and the directory)

But when Mule tries to deploy the apps, it gives the following errors. Is there something that I’m missing?

INFO 2017-02-28 09:54:10,953 [WrapperListener_start_runner]   org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: file:/C:/EDP_POC/MULE/mule-standalone-3.8.0/apps/zz_pru1.zip ERROR 2017-02-28 09:54:10,974 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ + Failed to deploy artifact ‘zz_pru1’, see below + ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Artifact directory does not exist: ‘C:\EDP_POC\MULE\mule-standalone-3.8.0\domains\zz_pru_domain’ at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactFactoryUtils.getDeploymentFile(ArtifactFactoryUtils.java:40) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.findDomain(DefaultDomainFactory.java:75) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:60) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:23) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createAppFrom(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:70) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:52) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:24) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.installFrom(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:493) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedInstallFrom(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:474) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:145) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) ~[mule-module-reboot-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788) ~[wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3] INFO 2017-02-28 09:54:10,974 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: file:/C:/EDP_POC/MULE/mule-standalone-3.8.0/apps/zz_pru2.zip ERROR 2017-02-28 09:54:10,992 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ + Failed to deploy artifact ‘zz_pru2’, see below + ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Artifact directory does not exist: ‘C:\EDP_POC\MULE\mule-standalone-3.8.0\domains\zz_pru_domain’ at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactFactoryUtils.getDeploymentFile(ArtifactFactoryUtils.java:40) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.findDomain(DefaultDomainFactory.java:75) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:60) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultDomainFactory.createArtifact(DefaultDomainFactory.java:23) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createAppFrom(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:70) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:52) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultApplicationFactory.createArtifact(DefaultApplicationFactory.java:24) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.installFrom(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:493) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedInstallFrom(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:474) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:145) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111] at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) ~[mule-module-reboot-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]

Thanks in advance for your support. Roberto

Comment: Check the domain name referencing from applications and the name of the domain is deployed on standalone server domains folder are same. It should be same, otherwise apps will fail to deploy on standalone server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but unfortunately the names are the same.

Comment: Can you share your Application mule-deploy.properties file values?

Comment: Hi again, you were right, I have checked again and there was a double "_" in the folder name. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can put it as an answer and can accept it to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RamakrishnaN, I solved the problem.

The Domain name was incorrect in mule standalone, for that reason the app couldn't find it.

Cheers
Roberto

Comment: "Domain name was incorrect in mule standalone" - Where was it incorrect? Where did you Change it?